# How can I get the current computer's ODRecord via Apple's Open Directory, without hardcoding any particular Active Directory domains/names in my app?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, active-directory

Apple provide the [Open Directory framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/opendirectory) for [their Active Directory implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Open_Directory).

How can I use their Open Directory framework to get the "bound" `ODNode` object and "this" computer's `ODRecord` object?

What I mean by this is that, from the command line, I can use `dsconfigad -show` to get some info like:

```
Active Directory Forest      = ad-root.local
Active Directory Domain      = example.com
Computer Account             = serno123$
```

But I'm not sure how to get access to those "Domain" and "Computer Account" from my Swift/Objective-C code **without hardcoding**. I am able to see some relevant nodes with a code snippet like

```swift
do {
  let nn = ODSession.default().nodeNames()
  print("Node names: \(nn)")
} catch {
  print("ERROR: \(error)")
}
```

which logs something like:

> Node names: [/Active Directory/EG, /Active Directory/EG/ad-root.local, /Active Directory/EG/example.com, /Contacts, /Local/Default, /Search]

but its unclear how to get the "this computer is bound to X via computer account Y" information it seems I would need to jump from one of these nodes (which one?) to having the `ODRecord` representing the computer my code is running on.

If I had the "Active Directory Domain = example.com" info available to my code I think I could get the right node via:

```swift
let adDomain = "example.com"
let adExtraPart = "EG"     // where does this come from?

let nameToSearch = "/Active Directory/\(adExtraPart)/\(adDomain)"
do {
  let n = try ODNode(session: ODSession.default(), name: nameToSearch)
  print("Node: \(n)")
  
  mainAdNode = n;     // [used below]
} catch {
  print("ERROR: \(error)")
}
```

But I don't know how to get the `adDomain` or `adExtraPart` configuration dynamically.

Similarly if I could get that far then for the computer's record I could do something like:

```swift
let n = mainAdNode   // e.g. from snippet above
let computerAccount = "serno123$"

do {
  let r = try n.record(withRecordType: kODRecordTypeComputesr, name: computerAccount, attributes: nil)
  print("Record: \(r)")

  computerRecord = r    // the object I want to use in my code…
} catch {
  print("ERROR: \(error)")
}
```

but again it is unclear where I could obtain the `computerAccount` value without hardcoding it or making assumptions re. its relationship to the hostname or whatnot.

To be clear, I'm not *necessarily* looking to use the exact APIs above. If instead I could simply:

```swift
let mainAdNode = try ODSession.default().domainNode()
let computerRecord = try mainAdNode.computerAccount()

// …
```

that would be even better!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but I did find that there is an `ODNodeType` that corresponds to something usable as the "main" or "default" node:

```
let adNode = try ODNode(
  session: ODSession.default(),
  type: ODNodeType(kODNodeTypeAuthentication)
)
```

As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/opendirectory/opendirectory_functions/1497602-node_types) says, this isn't just for authentication but is [emphasis added] a "node used for authentication **or record lookups**." On my machine and probably elsewhere, it returns the `/Search` node in practice.

As to the second part of my question, **if** the computer's Active Directory identifier is *already* known then one can use the `/Search` node obtained above to retrieve it:

```
let computerRecord = try adNode.record(
  withRecordType: kODRecordTypeComputers,
  name: "\(computer.id)$",
  attributes: nil
)
```

…but of course this still "hardcodes" the machine name or at least presumes knowledge of how to get it via some other mechanism, rather than the Active Directory "domain binding" itself :-/